# Foundation 6 Reveal Modal not properly resizing with dynamic data

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

The following basic Foundation 6 setup with a modal form is working. And with working I mean, once the modal form is on screen it resizes properly when I change the size of the browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>modal test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerContainer">
        <a href="#" class="button" data-open="modalForm">Show Modal</a>
    </div>
    <div id="modalContainer">

        <!-- start: modalForm content -->
        <div class="reveal" data-reveal id="modalForm" role="dialog" >
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="medium-12 large-12 columns">
                    <p>modal test</p>
                    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- end: modalForm content -->


    </div>
    <script src='js/foundation.min.js'></script>
    <script>
       //$("#modalContainer").load("_form-modal-test.html", function() {
        $(document).foundation();
         //});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I place the contents in an external file an load it like in the example below. The modal form no longer resizes properly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>modal test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerContainer">
        <a href="#" class="button" data-open="modalForm">Show Modal</a>
    </div>
    <div id="modalContainer"></div>
    <script src='js/foundation.min.js'></script>
    <script>
       $("#modalContainer").load("_form-modal-test.html", function() {
        $(document).foundation();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows how to get the modal form properly responsive when loaded dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried calling foundation on the element e.g. calling `$(this).foundation();` instead of `$(document).foundation();`

Comment: $(this).foundation(), $('#modalContainer').foundation() and $('#modalForm').foundation() don't seem to be the solution. Thank you for trying...

Comment: Foundation 5 has a reflow method, which has been removed in Foundation 6, which doesn't make sense. I use reflow all the time for situations like yours.

Comment: From what I understood is that F6's .foundation() replaces replaces/includes `reflow`, but perhaps it's not working properly (yet). I actually never tried F5, but I might look into it, because I already spent way to much time on these cosmetics... thanks again. The strange thing is that all foundation attributes are placed in the modal div, but it seems to lack `data-events="resize"` when dynamically loaded

Comment: I read that also, but it isn't the same because you have to invoke it for each individual element, rather than on the DOM, like in F5.

Comment: Hope this helps you or someone else, I had strange problems with the modal size and position (updating from foundation 5 to 6).  It was simply in the Foundation 6 example it does not have href="#" on the button.  Try removing it so your buttom is as follows

    <a class="button" data-open="modalForm">Show Modal</a>

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing it to resize the same way Foundation does. In this example reveal would be a variable using Foundation.Reveal(jQueryElement). See the next snippet for another example of using Foundation.Reveal().

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  reveal._setPosition();
});
```

You could also try loading it slightly different. This technique seems to work for me.

```
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1">
  <p>Some random text. Not loading the json file here.</p>
</div>    

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
  var modal = $('#exampleModal1');
  var reveal = new Foundation.Reveal(modal);
  $('button').click(function(){
    $.ajax('test.html')
      .done(function(resp){
        modal.html(resp);
        reveal.open();
    });
  });
</script>
```

I uploaded a Plunker you can run http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/JcWnxTJg2Viy3qCKMUoB/ or edit http://plnkr.co/edit/JcWnxTJg2Viy3qCKMUoB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way of setting the reveal component to work dinamically in a perfect way is by following this pattern:

- Write a function that returns a string with the HTML code you want to implement inside the reveal (so that in the view, you only have ). Let's call this function `revealHtmlFactory()`. So it will return `<h1>My Dinamic Reveal</h1>` etc.
- Then, you set a handler for a button that will be the reveal toggler. 
  Let's call this `onRevealToggle()`. This handler will

  1. `$('#myReveal').html(revealHtmlFactory());`
  2. `$(document).foundation();`
  3. `$('#myReveal').foundation('open');`

In this way, you first (1) ensure the html inside the reveal is set the way you want it before calling foundation's initializer. There you can set all your responsive classes dinamically, or have multiple functions that return diferent HTML code. 
Next (2) you re-initialize the inner state of foundation. This is needed because it will ensure that the view is re-scanned in order to identify what has changed, where new things have to be added, etc.
Finally (3) the Reveal will be opened showing exactly what you want in the way you want it, reflecting the last state of the information and reloading everything in the view.

I hope this helps.